# Getting text from Jupyter text widget?

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook

I want to create an interactive Jupyter notebook. I'd like to have a Textarea, where if I enter some text, a function gets run on the text I entered. I'm trying:

```
text = widgets.Textarea(
    value='last',
    placeholder='Paste ticket description here!',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
display(text)
text.on_displayed(show_matches(text.value))
```

Then I want to perform some magic with `show_matches` and display a pandas dataframe (`diplay(df)`). However, this only runs if I explicitly run the cell and then again only with the predefined `last` string. I want it to run whenever I finish writing in the text area, with the text I wrote. How can I do this (eg.: How can I bind the `value` of the `Textarea` to a Python variable and run a function whenever the value changes)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use `Text` instead of `Textarea` you can connect a callback via the `on_submit` method. This gets executed once <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit in the text field.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display

text = widgets.Text(
    value='last',
    placeholder='Paste ticket description here!',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
display(text)

def callback(wdgt):
    # replace by something useful
    display(wdgt.value)

text.on_submit(callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer works but you need to execute the cell again every time you update your text value. Here's another solution using `interact`.

Write your function and let the widget take in the argument with a textbox

```
@interact
def show_matches(text='last'):
    # do your thing with text and get the result
    display(result)
```

This way the widget knows to display result in realtime as you update your text value, no need to run the cell again and again.

Comment: After add @interact, I've got the ValueError: cannot find widget or abbreviation for argument: 'wdgt'