# How to block execution until Jupyter widget's value has been changed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

### Busy wait: NOT work

Given the following code:

```py
from ipywidgets import IntsInput
from IPython.display import display

in_value = IntsInput(description="value")
before = in_value.value
print('before': before)
display(in_value)

while before == in_value.value:
    ...  # blocking until value is changed

print('after', in_value.value)  # never reach
```

Obviously, the loop will blocking forever as `in_value.value` won't be evaluated again. Is there any way to make it work as simple as possible?

It looks like not possible as the observer is running on the main thread. Thus the following method also not work.

### Blocking queue: NOT work

```py
from ipywidgets import IntsInput
from IPython.display import display
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time

q = Queue()

widget = IntsInput()
display(widget)
def getvalue(change):
    q.put(change.new)
    widget.unobserve(getvalue, 'value')
widget.observe(getvalue, 'value')

print(q.get())  # pending forever
```

### Async: NOT work

```py
import asyncio
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Text
def wait_for_change(widget, value):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    def getvalue(change):
        # make the new value available
        future.set_result(change.new)
        widget.unobserve(getvalue, value)
    widget.observe(getvalue, value)
    return future

text_input = Text()
print('before', text_input.value)

display(text_input)
future = wait_for_change(text_input, 'value') 
await asyncio.ensure_future(future)  # block forever

# never reach
print(text_input.value)
```

Is there any solution for this? I know there is a solution to use event callback to achieve the similar result. But what I am looking for is a method to get rid of the event callback like `on_submit(main_flow)` or `observer(on_change, 'value')`. I want to turn those callback style methods into a sync one, that allow users to display a widget and blocking there until they finish input.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/synchronously-call-javascript-function-from-python/10059/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/threading-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets/14674/2?u=fomightez), especially where the latter says, "rather than threads, consider using the event loop
if you absolutely need threads, consider still using asyncio, and a deque." Related to that you may want to see the code [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-widget-slider-from-a-function-without-using-multithreading/15524/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: @Wayne I have tried and it not works. I have updated my question.

Comment: I think it may be easier in your case because the `Text` widget you are using in your updated attempt has an `on_submit()` method you can connect to conditionals.

Comment: I hope you had also seen [the thorough answer to 'Kill a loop with Button Jupyter Notebook?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223447/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

An option is along the lines of this ....

You can use the `on_submit()` method for a `Text` widget as brought up in [an answer to 'Getting text from Jupyter text widget?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344733/8508004). That callback via the `on_submit` gets executed once the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is hit in the text field, and so when that happens you can trigger to evaluate if that is different using conditionals.

Here is your example fleshed out with that added, I think. To make it more illustrative I added a widgets before and after the text box so that it has a 'before' state and 'after' state that is only seen when text changed:

```py
# based on [Getting text from Jupyter text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344733/8508004) and [How to block execution until Jupyter widget's value has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77363909/8508004) and https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynb
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display

arbitrary_before_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Valid!',
)

arbitrary_after_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Still VERY Valid!!!',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}, #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004 for showing all description
)


layout = widgets.Layout(width='600px') 

initial_text_setting = 'before'
textwidget = widgets.Text(
    value=initial_text_setting,
    placeholder='Enter Value Here', # This is what is shown in box if you remove all text to start anew.
    description='Enter Value in this box & then hit return:',
    disabled=False,
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}, #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004 for showing all description
    layout=layout
)

out_vbox = widgets.VBox([arbitrary_before_state, textwidget])

def main_flow(wdgt):
    if wdgt.value == initial_text_setting:
        print(f"This was already '{initial_text_setting}', please enter something new in the text box.")
    else:
        display(arbitrary_after_state)
        print("Thank Goodness! Something new.")

textwidget.on_submit(main_flow)

out_vbox
```

You'll see if you clear the text box and enter 'before' again, it asks for something different.
Or if you just hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while 'before' is still in the box, it prompts, too.
Only after getting something different in the text box does it continue.

#### For JupyterLab (& probably more modern Jupyter Notebook 7+)

Note, that code above will work with the older notebook interface. If you are using JupyterLab you will see things like what is in the `print()` statements go to the 'Log' console because it expects better handling of output. So try this updated version with better handing out `output` via a context manager:

```py
# based on [Getting text from Jupyter text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344733/8508004) and [How to block execution until Jupyter widget's value has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77363909/8508004) and https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynbb
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

arbitrary_before_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Valid!',
)

arbitrary_after_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Still VERY Valid!!!',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}, #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004 for showing all description
)


layout = widgets.Layout(width='600px') 

initial_text_setting = 'before'
textwidget = widgets.Text(
    value=initial_text_setting,
    placeholder='Enter Value Here', # This is what is shown in box if you remove all text to start anew.
    description='Enter Value in this box & then hit return:',
    disabled=False,
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}, #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004 for showing all description
    layout=layout
)

out_vbox = widgets.VBox([arbitrary_before_state, textwidget])
out = widgets.Output()

def main_flow(wdgt):
    with out:   # based on past knowledge about stuff that goes to JupyterLab's log (https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419/2?u=fomightez) & reminder from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649816/8508004
        if wdgt.value == initial_text_setting:
            out_vbox.children = [arbitrary_before_state, textwidget, out]
            print(f"This was already '{initial_text_setting}', please enter something new in the text box.")
        else:
            out_vbox.children = [arbitrary_before_state, textwidget,arbitrary_after_state, out]
            clear_output()
            print("Thank Goodness! Something new.")

textwidget.on_submit(main_flow)

out_vbox
```

## Using `widgets.IntText()` as the value entering device

I noticed in your first example code block you had something along the lines of what I gathered was similar to `widgets.IntText()` as the target widget to use. The code below, in this section uses, that. It is adapted from the 'Jupyterlab-approved' version from above.

```py
# based on [Getting text from Jupyter text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344733/8508004) and [How to block execution until Jupyter widget's value has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77363909/8508004) and https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynbb
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

arbitrary_before_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Valid!',
)

arbitrary_after_state = widgets.Valid(
    value=True,
    description='Still VERY Valid!!!',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'}, #based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004 for showing all description
)


layout = widgets.Layout(width='600px') 

initial_text_setting = 7
inttextwidget = widgets.IntText(
    value=initial_text_setting,
    description='Enter Value:',
    disabled=False,
)

out_vbox = widgets.VBox([arbitrary_before_state, inttextwidget])
out = widgets.Output()

def on_change(change):
    with out:   # based on past knowledge about stuff that goes to JupyterLab's log (https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419/2?u=fomightez) & reminder from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649816/8508004
        if change['new'] == initial_text_setting:
            out_vbox.children = [arbitrary_before_state, inttextwidget, out]
            clear_output()
            print(f"This was already '{initial_text_setting}', please enter a new value.")
        else:
            out_vbox.children = [arbitrary_before_state, inttextwidget,arbitrary_after_state, out]
            clear_output()
            print("Thank Goodness! Something new.")

inttextwidget.observe(on_change,'value')

out_vbox
```

You'll note that it initially does nothing if the initial value of `7` is left. That is because the `IntText()` widget won't register any change yet. Once the value in it is changed to a different value either by entering or using the up and down arrows, it will continue. If it switched back to `7` later, it will alert the user that it should be a different value than `7`.

---

## Fancier control layering

Although I gathered the toy example provided could be accomplished with just ipywidget methods (I believe), in my comments below the OP I tried to point out that you could use other overarching control layers, combined with ipywidgets to control further. For those seeking something more along the lines of that who ended up here, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/synchronously-call-javascript-function-from-python/10059/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/threading-with-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets/14674/2?u=fomightez), especially where the latter says, "rather than threads, consider using the event loop if you absolutely need threads, consider still using asyncio, and a deque." Related to that you may want to see the code [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-widget-slider-from-a-function-without-using-multithreading/15524/2?u=fomightez).Plus, also see [the thorough answer to 'Kill a loop with Button Jupyter Notebook?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223447/8508004).

Comment: Thank you. I know that callback based solution works. The problem is what I want to achieve is to pop up a window to block the code of current cell, and then continue after user confirms. If it is not possible to implement in the sync way, I think the callback based async solution is my only choice.

Comment: "The problem is what I want to achieve is to pop up a window to block the code of current cell, and then continue after user confirms." It seems like that should have been in the post.

Comment: What I am looking for is a method to get rid of the event callback like `on_submit(main_flow)` or `observer(on_change, 'value')`. I want to turn those callback style methods into a sync one, that allow users to display a widget and blocking there until they finish input.